# Mongoose query $in with latest document on specific field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to query documents in MongoDB using find(), but it's not working to get documents I want. Say we have a documents

```
Pet = [
{project: "foo", date: 11111, data: "Lion"}, 
{project: "bar", date: 1111, data: "Tiger"},
{project: "foo", date: 2222, data: "Cat"},
{project: "bee", date: 3333, data: "Rat"},
{project: "pet", date: 4444, data: "Cow"},
{project: "yeti", date: 2233, data: "Dog"}, ...];
```

Then, I just want to query only 1 document of each project in the array of ["foo", "pet"]. From this sample data, i expect to get

```
[{project: "foo", date: 11111, data: "Lion"},
{project: "pet", date: 4444, data: "Cow"}]
```

I try

```
Pet.find({project: {$in: ["foo","pet"]}, {},{ sort: { date: -1 },limit: 1});
```

I get only 1 document as I set limit equal to 1. How can I do to get the expected query?

Comment: If I understand what you are asking you should do two separate queries, one for each project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly your question this could help.

Assumption: You have a collection called projects with the fields from your example.

```
db.projects.aggregate(
 [
 { $match: { project: { $in: [ "foo","pet" ] } } },
 { $sort: { project: 1, date: 1 } },
 {
   $group:
     {
       _id: "$project",
       firstProject: { $first: "$date" }
     }
 }
```

]
)

Note: You could play a little more with the $group section of your aggregate to show other records within the group

Answer (score 0):

you have to use aggregation

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "project": {
        "$in": [
          "pet",
          "foo"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$project",
      "date": {
        "$first": "$date"
      },
      "data": {
        "$first": "$data"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "date": 1,
      "data": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "date": -1
    }
  }
])
```

here is working example : https://mongoplayground.net/p/rIDuXTeHg4i

Comment: Thank you Saurabh. This one look good but it might have a problem if the latest is not $first. Answer from Orlaqp is look better for the case.